# Are Two Probabilities Added?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I've been reading about some psychology stuff and statistics, was just wondering if I should add these percentages. `psychopathy prevalence in males 15.8%, and 5.9% in females` should I add these to get the general population or should I get the sum divided by two?
Would this be 21.7% or 10.85% ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the overall prevalence of psychopathy in the population (including both males and females) then you would take a *weighted average* of the prevalence in these two subgroups, weighted by their contribution to the population.  If you are willing to assume an equal proportion of males and females in the population then the overall prevalence of psychopathy in the population would be a straight average of the two figures you give, yielding an overall prevalence of 10.85%.